# Media Query Margin Fail

Tags: css, media-queries, margin

So far all of my media queries are fine, except this one. I have an actual iPad and I am using a simulator as well as my client doesn't like his logo resting against the edge of the screen, so all I'm trying to do is either give it a bit of padding or a margin (padding didn't work either). I figure another pair of eyes wouldn't hurt - am I missing something here??

```
@media screen only and (min-width:768px) and (max-width: 1024px) {
    .site-header .home-link {
        margin: 0 20px!important;
    }
}
.site-header .home-link {
    background: url(http://client.savorweb.com/INWS/wp-content/uploads/2015/04/iwns-logo.png) left no-repeat;
    color: #141412;
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
    max-width: 1024px;
    min-height: 150px;
    padding: 0px 5px 0px 10px;
    text-decoration: none;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Show us an example and/or screenshot.

Comment: On a Test Server here: http://client.savorweb.com/INWS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your media query is malformed. It should be:

```
@media only screen and (min-width:768px) and (max-width: 1024px)
```

With emphasis on **only screen** instead of **screen only**.